# Resilience4j RateLimiter seems to ignore configuration

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice, resilience4j

I have a problem with Resilience4j RateLimiter

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final ExternalService service = new ExternalService();
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);

    final RateLimiterConfig config = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
        .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .limitForPeriod(3)
        .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(12))
        .build();

    final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.of("RateLimiter", config);

    final Callable<Response<String>> callable = RateLimiter.decorateCallable(
        rateLimiter, () -> service.get(200, "OK")
    );

    executorService.submit(callable); //fine in first period
    executorService.submit(callable); //fine in first period
    executorService.submit(callable); //fine in first period
    executorService.submit(callable); //should wait 10 sec and fine in second period
    executorService.submit(callable); //should wait 10 sec and fine in second period
    executorService.submit(callable); //should wait 10 sec and fine in second period
    executorService.submit(callable); //should exit with timeout after 12 seconds
    executorService.submit(callable); //should exit with timeout after 12 seconds
    executorService.submit(callable); //should exit with timeout after 12 seconds


    Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(40).toMillis());
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

In `ExternalService` I have some basic logging with localTime of responses. I think that it should work as I explained in comments, but my response is:

```
> Task :Main.main()
[12:24:53.5] Return standard response
[12:24:53.5] Return standard response
[12:24:53.5] Return standard response
[12:25:03.5] Return standard response
[12:25:03.5] Return standard response
[12:25:03.5] Return standard response
[12:25:03.5] Return standard response
[12:25:03.5] Return standard response

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 40s
```

So it seems that the first cycle is good, but after that, FIVE next threads are allowed by RateLimiter, and the last thread is never called.

Comment: I'm investigating it. I created an issue to track it. https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/822

Comment: @RobertWinkler can you provide now an answer? I see that issue is resolved

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it was a bug which was introduced in a PR which is part of release 1.2.0. The PR added the possibility to requests multiple permits per call. The bug was fixed now.

Comment: Please add an answer here so I can close it :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it was a bug which was introduced in a PR #672 which is part of release v1.2.0. The PR added the possibility to requests multiple permits per call. The bug was fixed now.

Comment: Unfortunately with 1.3.1 release this is still not working. For first 6 calls, it works fine, but the rest 3 are not throwing exception